# Constructing vectors using (nested)loops in R

Tags: r, loops, vector, sequence

I've scanned quite some fora on the internet but couldn't find a clear answer to my problem, hence I decided to post it here. The program I am using is R.

The following problem is where I can't seem to find a solution. I am tasked with constructing a vector (1,2,2,3,3,3...,10,...,10) using a nested loop (so no rep()). So far I managed to construct a list of all elements but can't manage to convert it into the desired vector. I have tried quite some methods, like converting the data into a matrix and transposing it etc.

So far not a single method has worked, perhaps someone with more insight on this matter could help me.

This is what I've got so far:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10)
    if (j<=i)
    {
      x = c(i)
    print(x)
  }
}
```

which provides me with:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `rep(1:10,times=1:10)`?

Comment: `x=c(x,i)` instead of `x=c(i)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies @NicE I am not allowed to use rep();

Comment: @user31264 Didnt work out

Comment: another option: `cumsum(sequence(1:10)==1)`

Comment: @Anderson - didn't you forget to initialize x?

Answer (score 0):

If storing the result in a vector, instead of printing it, is the remaining problem, this can be done this way:

```
result <- vector(mode = "integer")
k <- 1
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10)
    if (j<=i)
    {
      result[k] = c(i)
      k <- k+1
    }
}
head(result)
```

Comment: You should add some description to your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.