# using the "For" loop to estimate ARIMA models of different order

Tags: r

So, I'm trying to estimate the ARIMA model with different orders for a data set and then select the best model with the lowest information criterion. I tried doing this:

```
for (i in 0:5){
  for(j in 0:5){
fit<-arima(data, order = c(i,0,j))
   }
}
```

But it doesn't iterate over the given range and only estimates the ARIMA(5,0,5). Also, what should I do to have an object which stores the AIC criterion for all the combination of i and j?

Answer (score 0):

you can run this code below

```
for(i in 0:5){
  for(j in 0:5){
    print(arima(data,order=c(i,0,j))$aic)
  }
}
```

Don't forget to use the print() function inside the loop, because if you don't, you won't get any results. To extract a component of a model, you can directly use the dollar sign ($) like what I did above. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to store the result of a nested for loop in a vector. You can check on this link below
[Constructing vectors using (nested)loops in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250131/constructing-vectors-using-nestedloops-in-r)